# Удаление точки с конца строки при помощи регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть код, который разрешает пользователю ввод в поле `input` только числа, включая вещественные:

```
value.replace(/^\D/, "").replace(/[^.,\d]/g, '').match(/^\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?|^\d+/)[0]
```

Но он пропускает числа вида `1.x` и `1,x`, т.е где есть точка или запятая, но отсутствует дробная часть.

Буду очень благодарен если поможете пофиксить этот баг.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете поступить следующим образом:

```
const processedValue = value
   .replace(/^\D/, "")
   .replace(/[^.,\d]/g, "")
   .replace(/\.,$/, "")
   .match(/^\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?|^\d+/)[0]
```